# add values to multidemensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this javascript code which generate a multi array with static values:

```
var items = [ ["red", "blue"], ["green", "yellow"] ];
console.log(items[1][1]); // green
```

but now I would like to fill the values dynamically.
I tried this:

```
var items = [[]];
$.each($("input[name='checkboxColors1']:checked"), function(){            
   items[0].push($(this).val());
});

$.each($("input[name='checkboxColors2']:checked"), function(){            
    items[1].push($(this).val());
});
```

items[0].push... works, but items[1] not

> TypeError: items[1] is undefined

Where is my fault?

Comment: if `var items = [[]];` then `items[1]` is `undefined`. You can't `push` into undefined, you need to create the array first.

Comment: I have wrote you a full working code down below, as an answer, let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous... You can't expect two functions to be executed sequentially... :-)

This way can work... But you must initialize your initial array this way:

```
var items = [ [], [] ];
```

Since with

```
var items = [[]];
```

You only define one internal array inside the external array (`items[0]`), but you want two (`items[0]`, `items[1]`).

Comment: Which part of this is asynchronous? It's just looping over the inputs synchronously. And javascript isn't by nature asynchronous. Two functions called in order will execute in order.

Comment: The fact that JS is asynchronous has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @Suxino: you are right, but with the first version of the question it had... :-)

Comment: All javascript is asyncronous... the two anonymous functions you define will be executed in undefined order... But, as @Suxino noted, if you populate two difefrent variables (items[0] and items[1]), as you currently do, you can forget about asynchronicity... If, as in the first revision of your question, you populate *one* single array, you can find an undefined element...

Comment: Functions will be executed in the order they are called. If the function is passed as a callback to an async operation *then*  it will be called in the future. It is **totally** false to say `all javascript is asynchronous`.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry... I meant, "all javascript callbacks" are asynchronous... :-)

Answer (score 2):

`var items = [[]];` You issue is here.

items[0] is an array. but items[1] is undefined.
In order to work you need to define items as `[[],[]]`

Or to make it more dynamic you could do check before that $.each if the items[1] exists and if not create it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot push into an undefined array, you first need to create the array.

You're code has to look like this:

```
var items = [[], []];
$.each($("input[name='checkboxColors1']:checked"), function(){            
   items[0].push($(this).val());
});

$.each($("input[name='checkboxColors2']:checked"), function(){            
    items[1].push($(this).val());
});
```

Then it should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused about "push" function.
This function insert a new element on the last position of array.

For example

```
var items = ["grape"];
items.push("apple"); 
console.log(items); //["grape", "apple"].
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it by creating a Array object and assign values dynamically. In this way you can also define string key as well.Please see below

```js
var items = new Array();

    items[0] = 1;
    items[1] = 2;
    console.log(items);
```

```
//Uncomment above block to test.
var items = new Array();
var items0 = [];
var items1 = [];
$.each($("input[name='checkboxColors1']:checked"), function(){            
   items0 = $(this).val();
});

$.each($("input[name='checkboxColors2']:checked"), function(){            
    items1 = $(this).val();
});
items[0] = items0;
items[1] = items1;
```

Comment: @Mark Meyer just edited my answer now i have shared code snippet of sample code.

Comment: @MarkMeyer have you checked?

Comment: This is no longer throws an error, but it doesn't do what the OP wants. They want  `items[0]` and `items[1]` to be arrays, hence the title `multidemensional array`

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when you combine static multi-dimension array, with dynamically adding elements with push.

Try the following code, that is dynamic for the two dimensions.

```
var checkBoxGroupNames = ['checkboxColors1', 'checkboxColors2'];
var items = [];

var checkedChkBoxes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxGroupNames.length; i++) {
    checkedChkBoxes = [];

    $.each($("input[name=" + checkBoxGroupNames[i] + "]:checked"), function(){
        checkedChkBoxes.push($(this).val());
    });

    items.push(checkedChkBoxes);
}

console.log(items); // items now holds the two dimension array
```

For a cleaner code, you may put the logic that find checked checkboxes per group - in a function.

```
var checkBoxGroupNames = ['checkboxColors1', 'checkboxColors2'];
var items = [];

$.each(checkBoxGroupNames, function(){
  items.push(GetCheckedChkBoxes(this));
});

console.log(items); // items now holds the two dimension array

function GetCheckedChkBoxes(chkBoxGroupName) {
  checkedChkBoxes = [];

  $.each($("input[name=" + chkBoxGroupName + "]:checked"), function(){
    checkedChkBoxes.push($(this).val());
  });

  return checkedChkBoxes;
}
```